# Moved modules from vendor to code, modules not working

Tags: composer, vendor, local

I've removed a couple of modules from composer, and placed the folder/files into the app/local folder according to the structure als mentioned in the registration.php.

The modules are enabled as seen in the app/etc/config.php. However they aren't visible in the backend or frontend. I'm in developer mode so no need to push static files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use the Magento 2 enabled modules command: `php bin/magento module:status` to see a list of Magento 2 all enabled / disabled modules
2. Enable/ disable or uninstall modules in Magento 2

- enable a module:`php bin/magento module:enable VendorName_ModuleName`
- disable a module: `php bin/magento module:disable VendorName_ModuleName`
- uninstall and remove a module: `php bin/magento module:uninstall VendorName_ModuleName`

Comment: The modules were enabled. However the used modules, were using a class of an unused module. When adding the missing (unused) modules, everything was working as it should be.